# How to create a function that extracts a vector of columns from a table in R

Tags: r

I have the following question:

"Define a function pick_columns which accepts a vector v and returns a data table consisting of all of the columns in flights whose names are found in v. The skeleton of the function has been provided for you."

I have the following function:

pick_columns = function(v) {

```
return(flights[,v])
```

}

pick_columns(hello$month,hello$year) -- THIS IS MY TEST CASE

I need to have inputs that consist of either one column name or multiple column names that can extract a data table consisting of the column names inputted. I hope you guys can help. Thanks!

Comment: flights is the table name by the way and I'm tasked with defining a function which can take in a column name or a vector of column names attributed to the flights table. year is just one of the column names I used

Comment: See `?'['` and compare the extraction methods of `[` and `[[`

Comment: Are you looking for `flights[ , names.of.columns]` ? (with a character vector `names.of.columns`)

Comment: you can just pipe the vector on the flight df. `library(tidyverse) df %>% select(v)`

Comment: maybe return: `flights[, c(intersect(v, names(flights))), with = FALSE]` ?

Comment: v needs to take in a vector of column name(s) and if those column names exist in the flights table, it needs to return the flights table with the column names specified in the vector inputted into v.

Comment: The issue is that I have to use the function() function in order to answer the problem correctly. If they exist, then return(v) where v are the columns.

Comment: Its unclear ! what you are trying to do is subsetting df based on a vector of colnames. I don't see what is your issue. If you can update your Q, reflecting the issue you are facing with an example that helps to understand.

Comment: @user5249203 I updated it. I'm trying to extract columns that exist in my table "flights". I have to define the function v though.

Comment: @jogo I tried something like that. My current code I just editted above.

Comment: Your test case is bad. Your instructions say your function *"accepts a vector v"*, but your test case doesn't use a vector, it uses the full two columns! `pick_columns(hello$month,hello$year)` isn't a vector argument. It's two arguments, and each one is a column extracted from the data frame via `$`. `hello$month` is a column, and `hello$year` is a column. **Your test case should be:** `v = c("month", "year")`, then `pick_columns(v)`.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks! I think I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to handle it. I'm not sure why you are looking for a function though as there are straight-forward ways. Still let me demonstrate few ways, including a function.

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c( "a", "b", "c", "d" ),
  x = c( 3, 2, 1, 2 ),
  y = c( 4, 3, 4, 3 ),
  z = c( 8, 9, 6, 7 ) )

v <- c("name", "x")
```

**Sol 1 : Direct dataframe**

```
> df[,which(names(df) %in% v)]
  name x
1    a 3
2    b 2
3    c 1
4    d 2
```

**Sol 2: Function call**

```
pick_columns <- function(v){
  temp <- df[,which(names(df) %in% v)]
}

> a <- pick_columns(v)
> a
  name x
1    a 3
2    b 2
3    c 1
4    d 2
```

**Sol 3: Data.Table way**

```
DT <- data.table(df)
> DT[, .SD, .SDcols=v]
   name x
1:    a 3
2:    b 2
3:    c 1
4:    d 2
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Comment: @skatofia Good it helped you. Function is a bit trickier. Other ways are well known standard commands.